# How can I generate a restore cart link in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, shopping-cart

While Magento has a support for a persistent cart, I'd like to send out a restore-cart link in Magento.

Clicking this link should restore your cart contents even if you don't have an existing session in Magento. I've been looking for references for an implementation such as this but haven't had any luck.

Comment: Asking for a walkthrough to a complete module is a bit too much for the Q&A format of this
site. Besides that, with this vague information it's hard to give any good answer.
We simply don't know your requirements: when should the cart be saved and the link generated? How does it get sent out? Should the link automatically log in the customer? Should it work for guests? I'd suggest you to update the question with more details if you want conceptional answers that get you started.

Comment: **OR** try starting and if you hit a
wall, ask for help here and explain exactly what you try to do, why you are doing it and
what does not work / where you need help - then we can talk implementation details :)